# Before Update is being fired twice

Tags: apex, before-trigger, debug

I am trying to figure out what is calling my before update twice. Cannot see what is causing this.

**Background**

Object: Case
Workflow Rules: All disabled
PB: All disabled
Case Assignment Rules: All disabled

Any update on the case object is call my before update method twice.

See log: Search for **DEBUG/MG is this firing multiple times?**
[Debug Log](https://www.dropbox.com/s/05pd5409uslc5a1/debug.txt?dl=0)

Same code in dev org only fires once. Stumped?

**Case trigger (only one)**

```
    trigger CaseTrigger on Case(before insert, after insert, before update, after update, after delete, after undelete) {
    // Run Case Trigger Handler
    new CaseTriggerHandler().run();
}
```

**Handler class**

```
  public class CaseTriggerHandler extends TriggerHandler {

   public CaseTriggerHandler(){
    }

    public override void beforeInsert() {

}


    public override void beforeUpdate() {
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, 'DEBUG/MG is this firing multiple times?'
    }

}
```

Comment: Any chance that you update your Case in your AfterUpdate? If so, look into a so-called trigger stopper: Basically a static variable that has to be false for your trigger logic to run, and which you set to true in your first run.

Comment: Nope, nothing apart from debug statements   just this: public override void beforeUpdate() {
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, 'DEBUG/MG is this firing multiple times?');
      
    }

    public override void afterUpdate() {
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, ' afterUpdate - DEBUG/MG is this firing multiple times?');

    }

Comment: No active workflows either?

Comment: All switched off for Case & Case Comments

Comment: Oh, that was a silly question since you already posted that in your question.. :-) Could you possibly update it and add your code, so we can have a look? (Trigger + Handler)

Comment: Please add some code, and also investigate what other triggers on Case might cause additional updates as that is not clear based on original post.

Comment: If using `Database.update(somelist,optAllOrNothing = false` I had a similar experience. This is documented here: http://cropredysfdc.com/2015/04/26/245/

Comment: Only one Trigger I.e. CaseTrigger and CaseTriggerHandler (class). Not performing any DML in the method, have removed all this logic.

Comment: Roll Up summery could be reason for firing trigger twice.

Comment: Roll up summary - ok there is one standard roll up summary field on the case object from a custom object. At this point there are no child records being rolled up.

Comment: I will try and reproduce in Dev to see. I can code round this of course, but this isn't a simple case of recursive loop here. Post from crop1645 is interesting, but would have thought it would show up in the finest debug logs if it failed.  What about API version? I'm using 33.0 for both trigger and class.

Comment: Roll up didn't make a difference I am afraid. I hate not know why it's happening. Sounds like I will have to code around it.

Comment: What is the code of `TriggerHandler.run()`, or `CaseTriggerHandler.run()` (whichever one is being called from the trigger. And is this executing on a single record (not a batch of >200 which would execute your trigger logic a second time)? *as Peter grasps at straws*

Comment: Unfortunately I never got to the bottom of this, other than handling it in the code. Thank you all for trying.

Comment: Any managed packages installed?

Comment: This question seems impossible to answer without knowing what is in the ** TriggerHandler** class.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your debug log, you are insert a Log__c custom object. If that log is the master-detail child of Case, then it could trigger an update on Case.

See number 17 here: https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm

Comment: Log object is standalone, not connected directly to any object.

Answer (score 1):

In your comment you said:

> Nope, nothing apart from debug statements just this: public override void beforeUpdate() { System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, 'DEBUG/MG is this firing multiple times?'); } public override void afterUpdate() { System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, ' afterUpdate - DEBUG/MG is this firing multiple times?'); }

There is the code in this comment:

```
public override void beforeUpdate() { 
    System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, 'DEBUG/MG is this firing multiple times?'); 
} 
public override void afterUpdate() { 
    System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, ' afterUpdate - DEBUG/MG is this firing multiple times?'); 
}
```

And I don't see **afterUpdate - DEBUG/MG is this firing multiple times?** log in your debug log. Can it be that you didn't save the **afterUpdate -** part and it just prints 1 line for *BEFORE* and 1 line for *AFTER* update?

*P.S. It was too long to post as a comment, so I had to post it as an answer*

Answer (score 1):

The trigger is firing on Before **AND** After event.

You should add some logic like :

if (Trigger.isBefore) {
new CaseTriggerHandler().run();
}

if(Trigger.isAfter) {
//do nothing
}

Comment: The point of the TriggerHandler class is that it is supposed to handle that sort of stuff.  We don't know how it was implemented and so would have no idea if this is the case or not.